# How do I start a JVM with unlimited memory?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

How do I start a JVM with no heap max memory restriction? So that it can take as much memory as it can ?

I searched if there is such an option, but I only seem to find the -Xmx and -Xms options.

EDIT:

Let's say I have a server with 4GB of RAM and it only runs my application. And, let's say I have another server with 32GB of RAM. I don't want to start my application with 4GB of memory limit because the second machine should be able to handle more objects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't (or at least, I don't know a JVM implementation that supports it). The JVM needs to know at start up how much memory it can allocate, to ensure that it can reserve a contiguous range in virtual memory. This allows - among others - for simpler reasoning in memory management.

If virtual memory would be expanded at runtime, this could lead to fragmented virtual memory ranges, making tracking and referencing memory harder.

However, recent Java versions have introduced options like `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=n`, which allows you to specify the percentage of memory to allocate to the Java heap, instead of an absolute in bytes. For example `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80` will allocate 80% of the available memory to the Java heap (the default is 25%).

The `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage` only works for systems with more than 200MB of memory (otherwise you need to use `-XX:MinRAMPercentage`, default 50%).

You can also use `-XX:InitialRAMPercentage` to specify the initial memory allocated to Java (`MaxRAMPercentage` is similar to `-Xmx`, `InitialRAMPercentage` is similar to `-Xms`).

Comment: IKVM.NET supports this by default

Comment: @JessieLesbian IVMM.NET is a dead project though.

Comment: I am a maintainer of IKVM.NET

Comment: Well, according to http://weblog.ikvm.net/ the project ended in 2017.

Answer (score 27):

`-XX:MaxRAMFraction=1` will auto-configure the max heap size to 100% of your physical ram or the limits imposed by cgroups if `UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` is set.

OpenJDK 10 will also support a percentage based option `MaxRAMPercentage` allowing more fine-grained selection [JDK-8186248](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8186248). This is important to leave some spare capacity for non-heap data structures to avoid swapping.

Answer (score 1):

JVM is running on physical computer that has limited memory. Therefore JVM cannot have unlimited memory as far as the memory is limited by definition. You can however supply very huge limit in `-Xmx` option.

The question is however why do you need the unlimited memory and even more correct question is how much memory do you really need?

Comment: The point of the question is that the `-Xmx` option imposes an *additional* constraint on the heap memory. The OP wants to remove that additional constraint, so that the JVM, to use the OP’s own words, “can take as much memory as it can”…

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can use the `free` and `awk` commands to calculate an inline value like this:

```
JAVA_OPT_MAX_MEM=$(free -m | awk '/Mem:/ {printf "-Xmx%dm", 0.80*$2}')
```

Example Result (on a machine with 3950m of free memory):

```
JAVA_OPT_MAX_MEM=-Xmx3160m
```

The calculated option is 80% of the total reported memory.