# JVM Dynamic Memory Allocation in Docker container with UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap option

Tags: docker, memory-management, jvm

I'm running a JVM inside a docker container. I set memory limit for container with a hardcoded value. And I use new `-XX:UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` option for JVM. In this case JVM should allocate heap memory depending on the container memory.

JVM actually does it, up to some point. If you give 500Mb of container memory JVM allocates 444.5 MB memory as expected.

But then JVM gets stuck at 1.74 Gb of heap memory. Even given 8Gb of container memory, JVM still allocates 1.74 Gb heap memory.

I can allocate 4Gb of heap memory with `-Xmx` option.

How can I let JVM allocate as much memory as it can?

Comment: Can you post all the jvm flags that you're using?

Comment: `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1` but i fixed the problem. There was no problem actually. These flags work as expected and JVM allocates as much memory as possible. Problem was my docker memory limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start a JVM with unlimited memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717077/how-do-i-start-a-jvm-with-unlimited-memory)

Answer (score 2):

For anybody has the same issue,

it's local docker memory limit. My docker was allowed to use 2Gb of memory max so JVM was not able to allocate more than 1.74Gb of memory.

I increased memory that docker can use, now, JVM allocates 3.43Gb of heap for 4Gb of container memory.